# Debugging a Trie structure in Java

Tags: java, debugging, trie

Following is a Trie stucture I made in Java which supports `insert` and `search`.

I added a new field `outDegree` which is a number which is incremented whenever a character is added to the structure.

```
public class Trie {
    private class Node {
        Node[] children;
        int outDegree;
        boolean isLeaf;

        Node() {
            this.children = new Node[26]; // Assuming the word is only going to contain 26 alphabets
            this.isLeaf = false;
            this.outDegree = 0;
        }
    }

    private Node root;

    public Trie() {
        root = new Node();
    }

    public Node insert(String word) {
        if (word == null)
            return null;

        Node currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            int index = word.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if (currentNode.children[index] == null) {
                currentNode.children[index] = new Node();
            }
            currentNode.outDegree++;
            System.out.println(currentNode.outDegree + "\t" + word.charAt(i) + "\t" + index);
            currentNode = currentNode.children[index];
        }
        currentNode.isLeaf = true;
        return currentNode;
    }

    private Node searchNode(String word) {
        if (word == null)
            return null;

        Node currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            int index = word.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if (currentNode.children[index] == null)
                return null;
            System.out.println(currentNode.outDegree + "\t" + word.charAt(i));
            currentNode = currentNode.children[index];
        }
        return currentNode;
    }

    public boolean search(String word) {
        Node lastNode = searchNode(word);
        return lastNode != null && lastNode.isLeaf;
    }

    public boolean startsWith(String prefix) {
        return prefix != null && searchNode(prefix) != null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Trie trie = new Trie();
        trie.insert("animesh");
        System.out.println();
        trie.insert("animation");
        System.out.println(trie.search("animesh"));   // true
        System.out.println(trie.search("animation")); // true
        System.out.println(trie.startsWith("anime")); // true
        System.out.println(trie.startsWith("animo")); // false
    }
}
```

**Output format**: outDegree character index

**Actual Output:**

```
1   a   0
1   n   13
1   i   8
1   m   12
1   e   4
1   s   18
1   h   7

2   a   0
2   n   13
2   i   8
2   m   12 ==> the two strings match till "anim". Here should be the last increment
2   a   0  ==> wrong outDegree. Node[] has all outDegree's as 0, so why it was 1 here?
1   t   19
1   i   8
1   o   14
1   n   13
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1   a   0
1   n   13
1   i   8
1   m   12
1   e   4
1   s   18
1   h   7

2   a   0
2   n   13
2   i   8
2   m   12 ==> the two strings match till "anim"
1   a   0  ==> the outDegree should be 1 and not 2
1   t   19
1   i   8
1   o   14
1   n   13
```

I am not able to find the part in code which is causing this?

Comment: From what I can tell, the logic seems correct. I think your expectation might be the issue here. Where you are printing, you are printing the outDegree of the parent character not the current one. So when you are adding 'a', the outDegree that you are printing is that of 'm' which is correctly 2. Because it was 1 when you inserted your first word and incremented again before adding 'a' in 'animation'.